# Hangman Swing Applet Freezing

Tags: java, swing, applet

**How it works:** This is a swing applet for hangman.  The "message box" is to display how many guesses they have left and then whether they win or lose at the end. The "output pane" is to display the empty letter spaces and which letters they have guessed. (For ex: if the word is dog, it will display _ _ _ and if they guess a D, it will be d _ _).

**The problem:** When I run it, I can enter the word and push OK.  It displays only one underscore in the output pane and "You have 6 tries to make a guess" in the message box.  Then a bunch of errors pop up and the app crashes. I don't have an event handler for the second OK button where they enter their letter guess, but I know I need one.  I'm just confused which of the code I should move to that event handler.

[image]

```
private void okButtonWordWordActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                 
String wordToGuess = wordToGuessTextBox.getText();
    char[] underscore = new char[wordToGuess.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < wordToGuess.length(); i++) {
      underscore[i] = '_';
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < wordToGuess.length(); i++) {
      underscore[i] = '_';
    }

    int wordLenToGuess = wordToGuess.length();
    int unsuccessfulTries = 6;

    while(wordLenToGuess >0 && unsuccessfulTries >0 ){
        for ( int i = 0; i < wordToGuess.length(); i++) {
          outputPane.setText(" " + underscore[i] + " ");
                  }


        messageBox.setText("You have " +unsuccessfulTries+ " tries to make a guess");
        char guess = letterGuess.getText().charAt(0);
        boolean iscorrect = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < underscore.length; i++) {
            if(wordToGuess.charAt(i) == guess)
            {
                underscore[i] = guess;
                wordLenToGuess--;
                iscorrect = true;
            }
        }

        if(!iscorrect)
            unsuccessfulTries--;
    }

    if(wordLenToGuess == 0)
        messageBox.setText("YOU WIN!! :)");
    else messageBox.setText("Sorry! You Lose :(");


}
```

Comment: Your `while-loop` is blocking the event dispatching thread, basically, `wordLenToGuess` isn't been reduced to `0`, because if I don't make an accurate guess the first time, there are still letters to be guessed.  I'd encourage you to make use of the debugger and step through the code and understand why it's not working, it will help you better understand how you might fix it

Comment: See also [*"Are Java applets worth learning?"*](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/196500/110799)

Comment: 1) *"Then a bunch of errors pop up"* Always copy/paste error and exception output! 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're only getting one underscore is because you're constantly setting the text in the output pane as " " + underscore[i] + " ". every time you set the text you are effectively removing any text that was previously there.

For this problem you could add up the spaces and the underscores as one string before you set the text.

As for the exceptions, I would certainly add an exception handler; however, this won't actually solve the problem. In this type of situation, the errors are generally caused by mishandled arrays. I would double check them to make sure you are not initialising or calling elements that don't exist.